# Simple data fetch in Flux design pattern

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Flux design pattern has been such help in simplifying my web application. However I ended up directly calling web APIs for certain situations simply because Flux seemed such overkill for the job. I was wondering how others might have solved such problem in a Flux way.

[image]

As the diagram suggests, we created the Action via the Action Creator for all Web API calls. I will give an example scenario. Let's say there are 3 components that are interested in User Store changes at the moment. User clicks one of them to load a list of user's hobbies from the back-end. But I only want only that one particular UI component to display the list of hobbies due to the user's action. The other 2 components won't change at all. Traditionally this would have been a simple couple lines asynch call with a callback. If you are to religiously follow Flux for this,

1. You create an action via Action Creator with a specific reference ID
2. Fetch data via Web API
3. Upon receiving data, action is created using the Action Creator
4. User store listens to this result arriving via the action
5. Update the store
6. Fire store updated event, all 3 components react to that and check if that was for mine using the reference ID
7. then finally render with the data fetched in that 1 UI component

My app having many small parts that load data dynamically like this per user action, I decided to use Flux for things that many components have to share states with since the stores act as centralized state provider. How do you guys use Flux to do simple data fetches such as the one mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to solve this.

1. Let all the components receive the update and the component decide whether to update or ignore the update.
2. Split up your store and subscribe only to those which are need in the component. This approach can get messy with stores getting dependent on each other and simultaneous dispatch problem.

If you haven't used any flux library , [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux) is highly recommended. It solves this by allowing the components to subscribe to part of state(store) tree.